# Convert String Date object to util.Date object with pattern MM/dd/yyyy

Tags: java, simpledateformat, java.util.date

getStartDate method returns util.Date type object. I need to a way to convert "today" which is String type Date object to util.Date object with the format of MM/dd/yyyy
If i format "today" String date to Date object I get long date format.

```
public Date getStartDate() {

    try {
        System.out.println("startDate" + startDate); // prints Fri Jan 02 00:00:00 EST 1998

        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        String today = formatter.format(startDate);

        System.out.println("today" + today); // prints 02/01/1998 (I need to return Date object  in this format)

        DateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Date reformatedDate = formatter2.parse(today);

        System.out.println("reformatedDate" + reformatedDate); // Fri Jan 02 00:00:00 EST 1998

        return reformatedDate; 

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: The Date obj represents a date and not its string representation. There is no such thing as a "short Date" obj (unless I am misunderstanding your question), only a short string representation (which you are getting from the DateFormat object).

Comment: @trooper sorry about confusion. I did mean short date format such as MM/dd/yyyy. I didnt mean Short data type.

Comment: right, that is what is confusing. A date is a date - its toString() is spitting out the long representation (your reformattedDate) .. if you want a short representation, use DateFormat (as you are doing) ... the Date obj itself does not carry that formatting info. It seems you are wanting to use its toString() to get the short format?

Comment: @trooper I'm struggling with this issue since yesterday. Could you please post your suggestion as a code?

Comment: Try Changing `Date reformatedDate = formatter2.parse(today);` to `Date reformatedDate = formatter2.format(today);`

Comment: the code you posted isn't wrong. Your DateFormat is converting your Date into a String w/ the given representation - this is what you need to do every time you go to display the date - the Date obj itself doesn't carry the formatting info, so if you format your String back into a date, you get a full date (not the short representation).

Comment: @AkashRajbanshi I tried already. format() method returns String type object. But I need Date type object with the format MM/dd/yyyy.

Comment: THAT is the issue - you are calling toString on your Date obj and its returning the long string format. The solution is simple - don't call toString! use DateFormat every time you need to display the date.

Comment: @trooper Did you mean when I print the date using sysout, it automatically call toString and convert to long Date?

Comment: Yes, this line `System.out.println("reformatedDate" + reformatedDate);` is actually `System.out.println("reformatedDate" + reformatedDate.toString());` ... the toString is implicit whenever you use an Object where a String is expected. Converting a Date into a String in the format *that you want* is the purpose of DateFormat.

Comment: @trooper oh ok. I got you. Could you help me to understand how to avoid calling toString() and print with original format. Code example would be grate

Comment: well, you are really close - you only need the first half of your code. Create your Date, use DateFormat to get a String, print that String, done. There is no need for that second part where you convert the String back to Date (only to print it again using toString). Do that DateFormat business every time you have to display - keep the Date obj itself unmodified, its your internal representation.

Comment: @trooper I needed that conversion coz my method returning Date type object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79802/discussion-between-trooper-and-user2033382).

Comment: @user2033382 Please provide the code where `getStartDate()` is called. The place where formatting is important is in that code, not in the `getStartDate()` code.

Answer (score 0):

can do something like this to parse the date:

```
 Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
 String dateString = "02/01/1998";
 Date date = null;
 try {
    date = (Date)((DateFormat) formatter).parse(dateString);
 } catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar.setTime(date);
 int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
 int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
 int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
 String.format("%02d", month);
 String.format("%02d", day);

 String yourDate = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
```

Comment: yeah I realized that. Should be very simple for you to adjust to the format you would like and seemed like you were already fimilar with how to format dates from the original post. Was this helpful? Anything else you are having issues with? If needed I can adjust to the date format you are using

Comment: I tried my best so far. But at last i get Date object in long date format. All I need is return Date type object in MM/dd/yyyy format. If you can pls adjust it. Thanx

Comment: I've updated my answer take a look- let me know if you have any more issues. If you find helpful, please upvote/accept so others can see

Comment: Of course i will upvote if this helped to fix my issue. Thnx again

Comment: Your method returning String object. But all i need is Date type object with format MM/dd/yyyy. You can see my getStartDate method returns Date object.

Comment: What's the goal here? Are you wanting to print the date out formatted as shown? Use the date in a later method that will only use day/month/year? Either way the posted solution should be what you need